# shell_exec return null - monitoring of linux services

Tags: php, linux, service, monitoring, shell-exec

I need monitoring services of my linux server without shell and i write a new php script, which do this function. After run, script not write status of service.
For example - if i write this command in terminal -

```
service nginx status |awk '{print $4}
```

he is return to me result:

```
Run...
```

This script:

```
<?php
$nginx = shell_exec("service nginx status |awk '{print $4}'");
$bd = shell_exec("service mysqld status |awk '{print $4}'");
$jabber = shell_exec("service ejabberd status |awk '{print $4}'");
$cgi = shell_exec("service php-fpm status |awk '{print $4}'");
$mem = shell_exec("service memcached status |awk '{print $4}'");
echo "<b>Web-server nginx:</b> $nginx";
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Server MySQL:</b> $bd";
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Server Jabber Jabber:</b> $jabber";
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Service php-fpm:</b> $cgi";
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Service memcached:</b> $mem";
?>
```

if do this via php, all '$' functions return empty information about status of services.
How write this script correctly? Please, help :)

Comment: Maybe the `service` command isn't in the `$PATH` of the webserver, try using the full path to the command.

Comment: Thank you!
Command /etc/init.d/service status is work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the full path to the `service` command, since the directory it's in is not in the web server's default `$PATH`.